# Primes with exponent series

Tags: python, math, compression, primes

I was interested in finding out if I could compact a number using prime exponents. During my research into this, I came across several solutions one being the creation of a sequential series of primes that only output their exponent amounts to make up the powers needed to recreate the inputted number. One source is linked [here][1]

I have written a function similar to this below.  However, upon testing have found out my code is unrealistically slow for large numbers as the brute force approach is time-consuming in finding a number that can be used to the point where the count takes hours.  I have tried increasing the prime series used with poor outcomes.  Can someone suggest any way to improve or solve this issue? Or offer any different options so all numbers can be used no matter the size? improved efficiencies and structure?

Many thanks

```
def get_primes(n):
primes = []
num = 2

while len(primes) < n:
    is_prime = all(num % i != 0 for i in range(2, int(num**0.5) + 1))
    if is_prime:
        primes.append(num)
    num += 1

return primes

def get_max_prime_amount(num):
  result = num // 3  # Use integer division for max_prime
  return result

def factorize_with_errors(original_number, primes, max_prime):
  error_count = 0
  soriginal_number = original_number
  tCount = 0
  PrimeArray = {}
  ExponentArray = {}

  for tPrimeCount in primes:
      tCount += 1
      PrimeArray[tCount] = tPrimeCount
      ExponentArray[tCount] = 0

  max_prime_number = PrimeArray[tCount]
  tCurrentPrimeCount = 1
  tFactorisation = False

  while not tFactorisation:
          if error_count == 99999999:
              breakpoint()

          tQuotient = gmpy2.mpfr(gmpy2.div(original_number,PrimeArray[tCurrentPrimeCount]))

        if tQuotient.is_integer():
            ExponentArray[tCurrentPrimeCount] += 1

            if tQuotient > max_prime_number:
                if tCurrentPrimeCount == max_prime:
                    tCurrentPrimeCount = 1
                    error_count += 1
                    original_number = int(tQuotient) - 1
                else:
                    original_number = int(tQuotient)
            elif tQuotient <= max_prime_number:
                if tQuotient == 1:
                    tFactorisation = True
                elif tQuotient in primes:
                    for tKey in PrimeArray:
                        if PrimeArray[tKey] == tQuotient:
                            ExponentArray[tKey] += 1
                            tFactorisation = True
                            break
                elif tQuotient not in primes:
                    tCurrentPrimeCount = 1
                    FinalFactorisation = False
                    while not FinalFactorisation:
                        tQuotientNew = tQuotient / PrimeArray[tCurrentPrimeCount]

                        if tQuotientNew == 1:
                            ExponentArray[tCurrentPrimeCount] += 1
                            tQuotient = tQuotientNew
                            tFactorisation = True
                            break
                        elif tQuotientNew.is_integer():
                            ExponentArray[tCurrentPrimeCount] += 1
                            tQuotient = tQuotientNew
                            break
                        else:
                            tCurrentPrimeCount += 1
                break

        elif not tQuotient.is_integer():
            if tCurrentPrimeCount == max_prime:
                tCurrentPrimeCount = 1
                error_count += 1
                soriginal_number -= 1
                original_number = soriginal_number
                for sKey in ExponentArray:
                    ExponentArray[sKey] = 0
            elif tCurrentPrimeCount < max_prime:
                tCurrentPrimeCount += 1

ExponentArray["error_count"] = error_count
return ExponentArray



original_number = 288684097887703
input_amount_len = len(str(original_number))
max_prime = get_max_prime_amount(input_amount_len)
primes = get_primes(max_prime)
result = factorize_with_errors(original_number, primes, max_prime)
print(result)
```

[1]: https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/65/24/94/5733e3b760d3e3/US6373986.pdf

Comment: "Can someone suggest any way to improve or solve this issue?"  There isn't one ... unless you can use a quantum computer.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Current_state_of_the_art.  In short, this is not a practical compression scheme ... notwithstanding that someone has apparently patented this (erm) "method".

Comment: You could precompute the primes and read them from a massive file.  But factorization of large numbers is still an `NP` problem ... according to the experts; i.e. mathematicians.  No amount of clever coding will change that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Stephen.  As said below I'm looking at if there is a way to adjust the process to allow a bigger range of integers to be more compressible.  Currently,  If an integer is not compressible the scheme searches for another integer that may fit the bill.  This process can take hours to find if at all.  So the question becomes why are some integers very compressible and others not so much and can the inputted integer be adjusted and still be practically compressed?

Comment: There's simply no injective function that can map n bits to less than n bits. To recover the original n bits uniquely and exactly, the function must be injective, sorry. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function. The example in the pdf only works because it is a very special case, N-1 is 23-smooth. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number

Comment: According to this formula https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008215/number-of-smooth-numbers-less-than-x, if I've done the maths right, there are approx. 2.64*10^17 23-smooth 128 bit unsigned integers, and that's out of approx. 3.4*10^38. So for the general case, the 'fault' will be 20+digits, and if you use 7 bits per exponent, that's 63bits. It looks like a stupid compression algorithm to me unless you know your inputs are often close to smooth numbers.

Comment: You can pick all the super-smooth numbers you like, say _n_ of them, and you will _still_ need log2(_n_) bits to identify them. You can, for example, pick all 2-smooth numbers so that you need just _one_ exponent. If you pick _n_ powers of 2, you will nevertheless need log2(_n_) bits to identify them.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could find a way to factor large integers quickly (be it Shor's quantum algorithm or a miraculous classical algorithm), this would not provide any overall compression. The number of integers (*n*) that you want to be able to compress (regardless of which integers you pick) puts a lower bound on the number of bits that will be needed on average to represent their exponents (log<sub>2</sub>*n*), which is equal to the number of bits needed to simply represent 0..*n*-1 in binary.

Comment: I agree with your initial assessment. However, I'm interested in the pool of integers that are highly compressible and if there is a scheme that could be implemented to adjust an integer to meet said criteria and still be practically compressed.  i.e input range 124504366373007938615873327878126 gives an exponent count of 045433445 1 which gives around a  3/1 ratio of compression.  The questions for me now is why some ranges and not others? What can be adjusted? is it practical? Thanks for your input it is much appreciated.

Comment: My statement applies regardless of which integers you pick.

Comment: Thanks again for your time Mark.  Maybe I am misunderstanding your statement. If you can spare the time can you use the example above? From the current paper, you don't need to identify the exponents as they are in sequential prime order. So you would receive/store 045433445 1 only, and not the primes themselves. Then you would only need to run 2^0*3^4*5^5*7^4*11^3*13^3*17^4*19^4*23^5+1 to return the integer.

Comment: If you're only coding _one_ number (124504366373007938615873327878126), then you need _zero_ bits to encode it! You need to pick a _set_ of _n_ numbers that you want to code. You can simply number the elements of the set 0.._n_-1, and send that number, using log2(_n_) bits. Now come up with a scheme that can code all of those numbers once using less than _n_ log2(_n_) bits. If you do, your scheme cannot be decoded, since at least two of your numbers coded to the same code. When you receive that code on the other end, you won't know which number it represents.

Comment: In doing this, you need to come up with the _actual_ encoding scheme. What does "045433445 1" even mean? Are you sending those ASCII characters, eight bits each? Are you sending four bits each, with the space as 15? Either way, what do you do if an exponent exceeds 9 or 14? If you have not written a program that takes an input and produces an output, then you do not have an encoding scheme. If you have not written a decoder program to take only that output as input, and write out the original input out in all cases, then you do not have a compression scheme.

Comment: I hold the same skepticism as you. I'm looking at this as a thought experiment only.  I have attached the binary representation to further describe how a scheme could work.  1  0 4 5 4 3 3 4 4 5 would be 00000001 000 100 101 100 011 011 100 100 101.  Each is identified by the prime sequence no matter the size of the exponents.  Each would be separated by a space to match each sequential prime. A complete scheme? definitely not.  But interesting for me nonetheless.

Comment: There is no skepticism needed here. It is simply a fact that you cannot compress in this way.

Comment: What do you mean by "a space". There are no spaces in binary. Just 0's and 1's. How do you know when one exponent has ended, and another begun?

Comment: Please see the excerpt from the provided paper.  "This data is converted into binary form at step S124, with
the first eight bits corresponding to the fault/error value and the
Subsequent Set of nine 3 bit values corresponding to the
exponents obtained for each prime number. The compressed
data to be transmitted is 35 bits in length, as shown in block
 The original data stream converts to a 103 bit binary
Stream."  Again I'm more interested in every way this could not work.

Comment: The linked patent is wrong. There are hundreds of invalid compression patents. The patent office knows to look for perpetual motion machines, but not so much compression of all data.

Comment: As I said, it takes zero bits to encode one number. They took 35 bits too many. (And even then, the encoding makes no sense.) To know if you have compression, you need to calculate the number of bits to encode and successfully decode all of the inputs.

Comment: I am done here. Good luck.